# When does Thread.CurrentThread.Join() make sense?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

What is the effect of calling Thread.CurrentThread.Join(), and if/when would it make sense to call it?

Comment: have you read the documentation?

Comment: Did you see this in some code somewhere?  It's pretty awful to even consider calling this.

Comment: You should call `t.Join()` on _another_ thread `t`, not on the current thread. See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx).

Comment: @ReedCopsey -- Thanks Reed.  I had seen this in some code and couldn't understand why it was added.  I wanted to be sure I didn't miss some clever use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the effect of calling Thread.CurrentThread.Join()

You will block the execution of the current thread, and effectively dead lock it.  It will cause the current thread to block until the current thread finishes, which will never happen.

> , and if/when would it make sense to call it?

It really doesn't make sense to do this.  You should never call this method in this manner.

---

On a side note, since you're using .NET 4, I would recommend avoiding using `Thread.Join` in general.  Using the new `Task`/`Task<T>` classes is far nicer in many ways, as you can easily attach continuations (or always call `Task.Wait()` if you truly need to block).

Answer (score 17):

Was it really

```
CurrentThread.Join()
```

that you saw in real code - which I kind of doubt, unless it's some hack to prevent other threads to join on the current thread - or was it

```
CurrentThread.Join(someTimeout)
```

The latter is equivalent to

```
Thread.Sleep(someTimeout)
```

except that joining on the current thread allows message pumping to continue if you are in a GUI / COM situation.

Comment: Your comparison helpt me much! I have a Windows Service test where I start the service, then wait some time with Thread.Sleep then continue, then pause and then stop. During this test I have a Thread.Sleep of 120 seconds. I then get the ContextSwitch error because the Thread.Sleep is not able to continue the message pump. If I change the Thread.Sleeps in CurrentThread.Join then the problem goes away.

Answer (score 3):

It actually make sense in world of observable. Lets say you have a queue listener in main and you want to keep main thread running forever.
Instead of doing while(true) and put your code in the loop, last line you can write this. This way current thread will also be parent thread for other threads spawned within the application.
Think of it as entry point for app.

Answer (score 2):

**No, CurrentThread.Join() makes no sense**
 This could make your program stop running, making the thread *A* wait for thread *A* for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making a unit test that tests if timers perform well in lets say a Windows Service and you use Thread.Sleep() statements with more as 60 seconds in it you can get ContextSwitch errors because the Thread.Sleep() is blocking the message pump.

If you are replacing those Thread.Sleep() statements in your unit test with Thread.CurrentThread.Join() then those ContextSwitch error will go away. So its a non blocking solution.

You could say Thread.CurrentThread.Join() is a better Thread.Sleep().

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentThread.Join()` can be used to put the current thread to sleep until another thread interrupts it.

For example, you may have a server where the main method sets up a pool of other threads to handle incoming requests, passes a reference to it's current thread to a shutdown-trap, and then goes to sleep until it's time for the server to shut down.

This is not a *terribly common* pattern but it would be wrong to say that there is **no** case where you'd want your current thread to sleep until interrupted.

Comment: *"until another thread interrupts it."* -- Are you referring to the [`Thread.Interrupt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.interrupt) method?