# Difference between Thread.Sleep(period) and Thread.CurrentThread.Join(period)

Tags: c#

Somebody could explain to me what is exactly the difference between Thread.Sleep(period) and Thread.CurrentThread.Join(period)?

Comment: See [When does Thread.CurrentThread.Join() make sense?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072576/when-does-thread-currentthread-join-make-sense). Also, explaining what you actually are trying to do (i.e. what made you come up with this question) can help the usefullness of the answers you'll be getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `Thread.Sleep` blocks the thread for a specific amount of time while `Thread.Join` blocks it until the target thread has terminated.

Considering that `Thread.CurrentThread` is not going to be terminated while it's suspended (even if it is terminated externally that makes no difference because it's dead), the end result is going to be the same. However, using `Join` is confusing while `Sleep` is obvious. Deciding which one to use is no contest.