# IIS error when sending newsletter using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've a problem with sending a newsletter (to about 5000 people) in my mvc-helper class.

```
public static void SendNewsletter(string fromAccount, string subject, string eMailText)
{
    var userEMailAddresses = new List<string>();

    using (var dbContext = new dbEntities())
    {
        userEMailAddresses =
            dbContext
                .User
                    .Where(w =>
                        !w.IsDeactivated &&
                        !w.IsBlacklisted)
                    .Select(s =>
                        s.UserName)
                    .ToList();
    }

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < userEMailAddresses.Count; i++)
        {
            SendMail(fromAccount, userEMailAddresses[i], subject, eMailText);
        }
    }).Start();
}
```

This is my function which will be called in a controller. The next Code-Block is the sending function.

```
public static void SendMail(string fromAccount, string toAccount, string subject, string eMailText)
{
    var fromEmailAddress = new EMailModel(fromAccount);

    var body = string.Empty;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("\\App_Data\\Templates\\") + "EMailTemplate.txt"))
    {
        body = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    body = body.Replace("%%Subject%%", subject);
    body = body.Replace("%%Body%%", eMailText);
    body = body.Replace("%%Year%%", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromEmailAddress.EMailAddress, toAccount))
    {
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(body);
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(Statics.SmtpClient, Statics.SmtpPort))
        {
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmailAddress.EMailAddress, fromEmailAddress.Password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = Statics.SslEnabled;
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(mail);
                Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After approx 1300 emails, my IIS get the following error:

[image: ErrorImage]

How can I solve this problem? I need the newsletter system...

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000);` ???

Comment: We have a mail system that just falls over after processing too many emails. It appeared our mail server was getting chocked up so we put in a loop counter and a hang time, ie process 10 emails, wait 10 seconds, rinse and repeat.  It works fine now, maybe worth investigating in your case?

Comment: Personally I would be tempted to use a tried and tested asynchronous send and end rather than reinventing the wheel... such as EASendMail ... https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=13

Comment: As Hugo said.. ensure there is no spam filter at the email server, e.g. 100+ emails send in 1 minute = spam = block... are there any virus checks on the route? as they can also have spam filters.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander

Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000) is the same like Thread.Sleep(1000).

Comment: What do the logs say about the iis worker process failing?

Comment: @PaulZahra

No, all checks are disabled.

Comment: @HenningHeusser why aren't you using the new *Async methods? Also, have you tried using the new (since .Net 4.5.2) `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` ?

Comment: @HenningHeusser join and sleep aren't quite the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001755/difference-between-thread-sleepperiod-and-thread-currentthread-joinperiod

Comment: I advise to look into the machine.config of your IIS and consider field values such as maxIoThreads and maxWorkerThreads and also in aspnet.config at the values for maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU, 
maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU and requestQueueLimit

Comment: You should really consider usign something like [Hangifre](http://hangfire.io/) for jobs like these.

Comment: What happens when changing or omitting the sleep?

Comment: Final comment before doing some work... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140308/how-to-send-mails-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

I've found a lot of errors, why it doesn't work.

The first one was a security setting in MailEnable. On MailEnableAdmin -> Servers -> Localhost -> Servers and Connectors -> Rightclick on SMTP and Settings -> Security-Tab there was a checkmark on a limit of receipiants (1000). I've unchecked it and restarted the Server.

After this, there was a unvalid E-Mail-Address in my User-List. Then I've created an E-Mail-Check-Funtion:

```
    private static bool IsValidEMail(string eMailAddress)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(eMailAddress, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(eMailAddress))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

and I've updated my send-function to

```
    public static void SendMail(string fromAccount, string toAccount, string subject, string eMailText)
    {
        if (!IsValidEMail(toAccount))
        {
            var invalidEMailAddress = toAccount;

            toAccount = "administrator@YOUR-DOMAIN.com";
            subject = "E-Mail-Address is invalid";
            eMailText = String.Format("Dear Administrator,<br><br>the following E-Mail-Address is invalid:<br><br>{0}", invalidEMailAddress);
        }

        var fromEmailAddress = new EMailModel(fromAccount);

        var body = string.Empty;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("\\App_Data\\Templates\\") + "EMailTemplate.txt"))
        {
            body = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        body = body.Replace("%%Subject%%", subject);
        body = body.Replace("%%Body%%", eMailText);
        body = body.Replace("%%Year%%", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromEmailAddress.EMailAddress, toAccount))
        {
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(body);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(Statics.SmtpClient, Statics.SmtpPort))
            {
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmailAddress.EMailAddress, fromEmailAddress.Password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = Statics.SslEnabled;
                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the SendNewsletter-Function is the same. Now, all E-Mails go out.

Thanks a lot to all users who helped!